# Sources Allowing Listening to Christian Music?

Tags: halacha, christianity, music

I read Igros Moshe forbids listening to music with idolatrous intent. What are some sources, if any, that allow listening to, or playing/performing Christian classical music, such as Bach's or Handel's oratorios? And what about Christian music without words, or words exclusively from Tanach?

Comment: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/goyishe-music-listening-to-music-of-gentile/

Comment: Ty. Anyone giving other sources would also be greatly appreciated. Maybe it's not the best translation, but it seems very contradictory. It first says one must not listen to music composed for idolatry, and then near the bottom implies that Christian classical music can be listened to.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dovid and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: My wife is a former Christian. She was shocked how much Ashkenazi music is just Christian music but slightly altered and with different words. Sepharadim also borrowed local Arab hits and incorporated it into their liturgy. I can only imagine these halakhot forbidding Christian music is a response to seeing how much appropriation has already happened and is an attempt to stop the flow

Comment: @Aaron not sure how true this story is but here it goes, the Rebbe of Ropshitz (or so I remember) said that after the destruction of the בית המקדש the leviyims Shira was disbursed between other nations but they are still holy and that is why some of them found there way back to the Jewish kehillos

Comment: I hope this thread gets more answers, but I will add to the discussion of similarities between Christian and Jewish music. I took a music history class in college that was mainly focused on christian music.... (Continued below.)

Comment: over the past millennium—maybe a little longer even. It's unbelievable how much Jewish music and tradition is borrowed in Christian liturgical music. There is even a form of large scale Christian music called a 'Requiem', in which.... (Continued below.)

Comment: there's a movement called 'Sanctus', where "Sanctus" (the Latin word for Kodosh) is repeated over and over, just like in the Kedusha, which is its widely accepted origin. The melodies are incredibly beautiful, and definitely sound "Jewish" in a way, but in a more refined and organized way, where the composer knew exactly what they are doing. I have no doubt that a Jew can get a better idea of how our music sounded closer to the times of the Beis Hamikdash by listen and/or stuying these works. Not to say that some manyanim are singing the tefilos "correctly" now, but the.... (Continued below.)

Comment: fact is that most Jews are not musically trained and most manyanim do not sing the most coherent melodies and are often very off pitch. Still a thing of beauty, but could use some improvement for sure. Anyway, I used a lot of brain cells just now, so I hope the very few people who read this post have enjoyed my two cents, prior or after to answering my above question!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a specific source, but the following may be relevant.

One of my Rabbeim once explained to me regarding classical music that "music is not mekabel tumah". However, if there are identifiable religious connotations then it may be problematic. For example, if you listen to a famous religious choral work (Bach's Mass B minor or Mozart Requiem, etc.) but replaced all the words with "lah lah lah", then although the narrative of the words is gone, the essential nature of the piece may still remain when you listen to it. I would imagine that the images and feelings that the piece evokes changes from person to person and would make a difference as to whether it may be permissible or not.

Having said this, there are several classical (small 'c') music forms which almost always comprise a religious (Christian text) element, e.g., Requiem, Mass, Chorale, Hymn, Motet, Gregorian Chant, etc.

There are two sides: If you are a musical expert and can tell the precise form of the music from the structure, tone, etc. then you may be able to directly identify if you are listening to a religious work. You may even come to associate a particular melody with the precise words as they correspond to the Christian bible, for example. On the other hand, if you are ignorant of classical music entirely, there may be no Christian connotation even to works that have an explicit religious nature. The same music will affect different people differently.

A final decision regarding the matter is best left to the individual person, their situation and probably in discussion with a Rav that they are acquainted with.